# $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a double cover of $\text{SO}^+(2,1)$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am sticking with this:

Show that $\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ is a double cover of $\text{SO}^+(2,1)$, which is a component of the identity of a Lie group of $3\times 3$ matrices satisfying

$A^TJA=3\times 3$ diagonal matrix with values 1,1,-1 respectively.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2x2 matrixes with trace 0 and also with trace as the bilinear form has orthogonal basis
$$\Bigg\{
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
1&0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&-1\end{pmatrix}
\Bigg\}.$$
The action of $SL_2\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ on the space spanned by these matrices given by $g\cdot x=gxg^{-1}$ preserves the bilinear form since $gxg^{-1} gyg^{-1}= gxyg^{-1}$ and trace is invariant on conjugacy classes. The map to this copy of $SO(2,1)$ has kernel $\{ \pm 1\}$ so this is two copies, one to the connected component of the identity and one to the other.

Hope this helps! Stay safe